# Use maven repository as local ivy cache

Tags: maven-2, ivy

Is there any possibility to use local Maven repository (~/.m2) as local Ivy cache (~/.ivy)? They have different layouts.

Sometimes I use Maven and sometimes I use SBT which uses Ivy underneath, so I have 2 copies of same libs in both Maven and Ivy. I would like to use same dir thus saving disk space and network.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can specify the cache and the layout of the cache by using the

```
  <cache/> Tag
```

.

I think you will have to alter the patterns for the artifacts/ivy.xml files.
The Tag is described here:
http://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/2.0.0/settings/caches.html.
It seems that it should work, but I've never tried :).

Answer (score 24):

To save **network**, just [configure ivy to use local Maven repository](http://wayback.archive.org/web/20120813100551/http://tech.zhenhua.info/2011/09/configure-ivy-to-use-local-maven.html)

```
      <property name="local-maven2-dir" value="${user.home}/.m2/repository/" />
      <filesystem name="local-maven-2" m2compatible="true">
        <artifact
           pattern="${local-maven2-dir}/[organisation]/[module]/[revision]/[module]-[revision].[ext]" />
        <ivy
           pattern="${local-maven2-dir}/[organisation]/[module]/[revision]/[module]-[revision].pom" />
      </filesystem>
```