# ivysettings.xml: add local maven path

Tags: java, maven, ivy

How to add a local **path** (not URL) to `ivysettings.xml`? I need to add my Maven local repository (/Users/me/.m2/repository to it.

Thanks

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Try the following **ivysettings.xml** file:

```
<ivysettings>
    <settings defaultResolver="default"/>
    <property name="m2-pattern" value="${user.home}/.m2/repository/[organisation]/[module]/[revision]/[module]-[revision](-[classifier]).[ext]" override="false" />
    <resolvers>
        <chain name="default">
            <filesystem name="local-maven2" m2compatible="true" >
                <artifact pattern="${m2-pattern}"/>
                <ivy pattern="${m2-pattern}"/>
            </filesystem>
            <ibiblio name="central" m2compatible="true"/>
        </chain>
    </resolvers>
</ivysettings>
```

It includes Maven central in case the dependency is missing from the local Maven repo.

**Note:**

The benefits of re-using a local Maven repository are limited. Ivy caches jars retrieved from repostories.

Comment: It's worth considering forcing `.pom` extension in ivy patterns, like it's suggested [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9495810/3832536). This way Ivy's POM conversion logic will kick in, which is relevant if you need to reference synthetic configurations like `master`.

Comment: @mephi42 I did not know that, neat!  Using the Maven local repo is a bad idea IMHO. It functions more like a cache. Makes much more sense to configure both ivy and Maven to pull from the same remote repos!

Answer (score 3):

**Ivy dependencies are resolved with "Resolvers".**

This page is pretty good for understanding the basics of how they work.

http://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/latest-milestone/settings/resolvers.html

**Specifically : How can I "resolve" a local maven repository ?**

Ivy has a "FileSystemResolver" which, rather than taking in a web address, can simply resolve from a local, root path.  Note that there are some gotchas when things get complicated, like this one : http://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/latest-milestone/settings/resolvers.html .  Resolvers are similar to maven Repository tags, in that they define a resource.

**A quick word of advice**

Remember that once you customize ivysettings.xml if you are using an IDE, you will have to tell it to specifically use YOUR ivysettings.xml file, rather than some internal default.

Answer (score 2):

I found out that in the more recent versions of sbt you can do

```
sbt publish-m2
```

Comment: Awesome, how does the location of the Maven repository get modified with this command?

Comment: 'sbt publish-m2' publishes to ~/.m2 directory. Is this what you are asking?

Comment: Thanks @Always, I was trying to understand why SBT wasn't paying attention to ``<localRepository>`` in the settings.xml.

Comment: It's sbt publishM2 for me

Answer (score 0):

Prior to 0.13.7, SBT ignored the Maven's settings.xml to use the `<localRepository>` setting. See https://github.com/sbt/sbt/issues/1589. In some cases, this will obviate the need to change ivysettings.xml when using `publish-m2`.