# How to retrieve a war or zip artifact from maven repository with ivy standalone and without ivy module file

Tags: java, ivy

It is easy to use standalone ivy to download dependencies as along the artifact type is jar.

```
java -jar ivy.jar -settings ivysettings.xml -dependency groupId artifactId version -retrieve "/[artifact]-[revision](-[classifier]).[ext]"
```

But how I can tell ivy the other artifact type like (war or zip) if use ivy module file is not an option. In the example above ivysettings.xml contains only settings for local maven repository
 [explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8617963/ivysettings-xml-add-local-maven-path)

Comment: The configurations in the remote module is what determines should be downloaded. I imagine the "default" configuration has only contained jars in your case.

Comment: @MarkO'Connor 
Hi Mark thank you for you comment. It is my first interaction on stackoverflow and the question topic was wrong because actually I try to
retrieve a war artifact which is stored in maven repository. I have updated the question topic. So in my case that simple maven repository without any special remote module configuration.