# Pants build files integrate with maven repo

Tags: maven, pants

Is it possible to get pants to pull in dependencies from your local maven repo?

I have searched and looked into the pants build system (new to me), and have had no luck anyone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use ivy, configure the ivy setting per [ivysettings.xml: add local maven path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8617963/ivysettings-xml-add-local-maven-path) then have Pants pick up the ivy setting.

```
[resolve.ivy]
ivy_settings: /path/to/ivysettings.xml
```

If you use coursier,

```
[coursier]
repos: [
    <other remote repos>,
    # local maven repo
    'file://%(homedir)s/.m2/repository',
  ]
```

Comment: yes we do have an ivy settings file. Would this also work for remote repos?

Comment: > Would this also work for remote repos?

If you configure both local and remote in ivy settings, then ivy will look in both places in some order.